# Magento2, setItemCount for minicart does not work

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

To limit the number of product displaying in minicart, I wrote in

```
app/design/frontend/myVendor/myTheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/default.xml
```

below but I see no effect!

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <reference name="minicart">
                <action method="setItemCount"><count>3</count></action>
            </reference>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: which version of magento 2 are you using ?

Comment: 2.1.7 Enterprise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also set limit the number of product displaying in mini cart using below steps.

1. Login to your magento admin panel
2. Set store configuration Maximum Display Recently Added Item(s) to `3

   (Located under Sales > Checkout > Shopping Cart Sidebar)
3. Clear caches

Comment: works like a charms, thank you.

Comment: @ZeeshanKhuwaja Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <referenceBlock name="minicart">
                <action method="setItemCount"><count>3</count></action>
            </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

You have to get `referenceBlock` instead of **reference** node.

Comment: Still diesplys more than 3 :(, do I need to deploy again?

Comment: which code have you written in phtml file?

Comment: the code is the magento default one

Comment: Have u tried above? do you get it working?

Comment: i havent try i have just give you referene for your xml use referenceBlock

Comment: Tnx but it did not work, don't you think maybe the xml file I'm referring might be wrong?

Comment: why we have to fix this on code level while this is basic configuration in the Magento admin panel and can be changed directly from there ?